# Create Link to specific tab Sharepoint document workbook

Tags: excel, sharepoint, hyperlink

I have a document in sharepoint that I need to create links to. I want to be able to point to individual tabs in the workbook.

But when I try something like this:

```
https://company1.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/Product/Messaging/PS-OW/NA-Region/CCMI/Project_MEOW/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B03C96B09-B5AA-4359-A39E-9A88F8626B71%7D&file=CCMI_Details_ClientCompany.xlsx#'Nodes'
```

Opening the link only gets to me to whatever tab I was already on. It does not change if I specify different tabs with names like 'DNS', 'Conf Keys' or 'Nodes'. How can I link this correctly to individual tabs within a sharepoint workbook?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint is unable to handle the "#'Nodes'" to link a sheet. There is no way to link to a specific SharePoint excel spreadsheet in the browser.

A similar thread for your reference:
[Open specific excel sheet from sharepoint URL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172007/open-specific-excel-sheet-from-sharepoint-url)